# Cocos2d pause game freezes the screen

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-loop, cocos2d-x, ccsprite

I am trying to create pause screen for my game. The game is developed upon continuous scrolling background (top to bottom) with obstacles which are moving independently (left to right).

Below is the code:

> PauseScene.h

```
@interface PauseScene : CCNode {}
@property (nonatomic, retain) HelloWorldScene *mainScene;
//+ (PauseScene *)scene;
- (id) init;
@end
```

> PauseScene.m

```
@implementation PauseScene

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Adding RESUME and QUIT button and few others to make the whole Pause screen
    }
    return self;
}

// Called the method when Resume button is selected
- (void) Resume:(id) sender {
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];

    self.mainScene.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.mainScene removeChild: self];
    [self.mainScene StartGame]; // StartGame in MainScene contains the same code which commented out above, I will paste StartGame method later
}

// Quit method is called when the Quit button is pressed
- (void) Quit:(id) sender {
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];

    self.mainScene.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.mainScene removeChild: self];
    NSLog(@"Pre Reload", nil);
    //[self.mainScene scheduleOnce:@selector(ReloadGame) delay: 1.0f];
    [self.mainScene ReloadGame]; // Reload method contains the code commented above
}

@end
```

**PauseScene is mere node class.**

> StartGame and ReloadGame methods in MainScene file

```
- (void) StartGame {
    // Create and display HUD layer, like, scores, navigation buttons, etc.

    // Resuming the game
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}

- (void) ReloadGame {
    // Resume the game
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorldScene scene] withTransition:[CCTransition transitionFadeWithDuration:1.0f]];
}
```

> The pause button is displayed in HUD layer of MainScene, so, when the pause button is clicked, we will pause the game and display the PauseScene

```
- (void)onPauseClicked:(id)sender {
    // Code to display the pause node of this scene

    // Pause the game
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}
```

When I comment out that `stopAnimation` and `pause` part the Pause and Resume works perfect. But when I implement any of these, at the time of quitGame, `replaceScene` is not working somehow. I think this is because game goes in pause mode but it is not working even if I call replaceScene using scheduler on delay of 5-10 seconds.

And if I don't use these `stopAnimation` and `pause`, some sprites which are given `CCAction` are not being paused and goes on even when my game is paused.

Your help is appreciated because I am using Cocos2d 3.0 and unable to find any proper help.

Comment: When hitting pause button do you add a pause menu node to your current scene or do you replace the current scene with a pause scene?

Comment: @fiddler I do add pause node on current scene. By the way, the issue is resolved as I tried it different way. Called paused method on each sprite/node in the game.

Comment: Good! Remember to post the answer to your question then, it might help other people who face the same issue

Comment: For answer to the question refer to the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970966/cocos2d-implementation-of-pause-the-game-scene-layer-issue